# Slow distinct count over large dataset

Tags: ssas

I have a cube where there is a single fact table about online customer orders.  each row contains a `basketID` and a `customerID`.  There can then  be multiple rows of the same `basketID`/`customerID` together with another ID for the item in the basket.

The number of distinct `basketID`s in my dataset is nearly 32 million.  The performance is therefore incredibly slow as a physical distinct count, particularly when I introduce dimension hierarchies.

I wonder if anyone has any tips on where to look to boost performance.  I have been running usage based optimisations on aggregations which helps bit by bit, but nothing hugely impacting.  I don't think I can do many to many, because whilst a Customer can have multiple baskets, a basket cannot have multiple customers (please correct me if wrong).  Physical RAM is OK at 128GB on the server.  A standalone count of basket ids is around a minute and some more complex drilldown queries can take 2.5- 5 mins.

I have exhausted Google and beginning to wonder if I will just have to make do with the slow count due to the volume of data, but wondered if anyone else has any avenues?

Comment: What version of SSAS? If you connect in SSMS Object Explorer what's the exact version number you see in the server node of SSAS?

Comment: Describe your hardware? How many cores and what type of disks? SSD? If spinning disks how many spindles?

Comment: SSAS version:  11.0339.0
Cores: 12
HD: Not SSD, but no more information than that I'm afraid at the moment

Comment: hmm. Can you check that version number again. Maybe it is 11.0.3393? Check it here and then consider upgrading to the latest service pack or even latest cumulative update. There are lots of fixes that can have an impact on perf. http://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com

Comment: Sorry, yes, fat finger, it's 11.0.3339.0.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend reading these white papers and posts. You might look into the optimizations it describes like partitions with non-overlapping ranges of basketIDs.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=65df6ebf-9d1c-405f-84b1-08f492af52dd&displaylang=en

This old post describes the performance gain of SSD for distinct counts:
https://web.archive.org/web/20101129205756/http://sqlcat.com/technicalnotes/archive/2010/09/20/analysis-services-distinct-count-optimization-using-solid-state-devices.aspx

Based upon the 32 million distinct basketIDs I would delete all aggregations you have built. Aggs for distinct count measures are different. For a Sum measure on a dataset with 5 years of data a yearly agg will be just 5 rows. But for a distinct count measure the yearly agg will store one row per year per distinct count value. So it won't be much smaller than the raw fact table.

If basketID isn't a bigint I would find some way to make it bigint as that will help performance.

Comment: Thanks,

The original partitioning strategy I had chosen was by week.  Each week is a member of a 26 or 27 week bloc semester (chosen by business logic).

Due to the seasonal nature of the business, the number of distinct baskets can be very uneven.  Most weeks are around 600k baskets, but there are spikes to 700-1000k intermittently.

After reading the links, it appears a Time * BasketID slice might be the way to go.  I am going to create Semester main partitions and then slice on the basket IDs.  As I have 12 cores, I infer from the reading 12 slices will be optimal.  Will report back.

Comment: @TJB sounds like you are on the right track. If all 95% of queries filter by semester or put it on rows but don't get a grand total, then semester partitions make great sense. You really just need to try different strategies and see which one is best for your workload. It could be just basketID range partitioning (no semester) is best. Or maybe semester * basketID is best.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is from more than 3 years ago, but while I was looking into this same issue I ran across [this article](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/analyzing-distinctcount-performance-in-dax/) by Marco Russo about the combination of SUMX and DISTINCT.  After applying this logic to my Cube the query time showed significant improvement, from a query that would time out to something that finished in a few seconds, and returned the same result.